# Not able to launch one ec2 instance with count 1 and subnets(2) are created from the for_each loop

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Subnets are created from the below code:

```
    resource "aws_subnet" "Private" {
  for_each          = var.subnet_cidrs_private
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  cidr_block        = each.value
  availability_zone = each.key
  tags = {
    Name = format("%s-%s-%s", var.environment, "Pri-Subnet", substr(each.key, -2, -1))
  }
}
```

Trying to create 1 instance with count parameter.

```
    resource "aws_instance" "visualapp" {
  instance_type          = "t2.micro"
  ami                    = var.visualapp-ami
  key_name               = var.key_pair
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.visualapp.id]
  subnet_id              = element(aws_subnet.Private[*].id, count.index)
  count                  = 1
  tags = {
    Name = format("%s-%s", var.environment, "mage-varnish-${count.index + 1}")
  }
}
```

Getting the below error:

```
subnet_id = element(aws_subnet.Private[*].id, count.index)

This object does not have an attribute named "id".
```

Variables:

```
   variable "subnet_cidrs_private" {
  default = {
    eu-west-1a = "172.26.3.0/24",
    eu-west-1b = "172.26.4.0/24"
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`element` would be used if you had used `count`. Since you've used `for_each` you need to use `values` first:

```
subnet_id = element(values(aws_subnet.Private)[*].id, count.index)
```